# Getting error "requested resource /xxxxx could not be found on this server."

Tags: php, html, error-handling, ip

While directing to a page, I'm getting the following error in my php based web project:

```
Not Acceptable

An appropriate representation of the requested resource /DLD/login.php could not be found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I can direct to all the pages other than a specific page (login.php in my case). Whereas the same project with the same files are working fine at another server.

Comment: 404 typically means it's not found. Are you sure /DLD/login.php exists?

Comment: @DarylGill, yes 100% sure. 
Actually this page (login.php) contains login form, I'm able to login from admin's account but Whenever I enter user's credentials at login.php, it gives me the following error